# Error using QMediaPlayer with PyQt5 on WIndows

Tags: windows, video, pyqt, pyqt5

Attatched below is  test script that I was using in order to play sample video for PyQt5. Unfortunately, soon after loading the video, the mediaPlayer mediaStatus switches to code 8 (InvalidMedia) I have also tried this with a local version of the .mp4, to no avail. I have tried other files, but am unable to diagnose the problem any further. I found this implementation of media player elsewhere on Stack Overflow, so if anyone knows a completely different way of implementing it, I am open to that.

Additionally, I have tested the "tutorial" video player on my .mp4, but that didn't play anything either. [Github](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/multimediawidgets/videowidget.py)

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
import glob


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Navon test')
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # exit option for the menu bar File menu
        self.exit = QAction('Exit', self)
        self.exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+q')
        # message for the status bar if mouse is over Exit
        self.exit.setStatusTip('Exit program')
        # newer connect style (PySide/PyQT 4.5 and higher)
        self.exit.triggered.connect(app.quit)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.centralwidget = VideoPlayer()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        player = self.centralwidget.mediaPlayer
        print('state: ' + str(player.state()))
        print('mediaStatus: ' + str(player.mediaStatus()))
        print('error: ' + str(player.error()))
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_L:
            print('loading')
            self.centralwidget.load()
        # update : missed () here
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_P:
            print('playing')
            self.centralwidget.play()


class VideoPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.videoItem = QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self.videoItem.setSize(QSizeF(640, 480))
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        graphicsView = QGraphicsView(scene)
        scene.addItem(self.videoItem)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(graphicsView)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoItem)

    def load(self):
        local = QUrl('http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4')
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(local))

    def play(self):
        self.mediaPlayer.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = MainWindow()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got all the necessary video codecs installed on your system? Try running the example with a `.wmv` file to make sure that it works properly.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. I figured as much when not even the tutorial would load, but was unsure where to find the proper codecs. Thank you for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, attach my code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *

class VideoPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)
        videoItem = QGraphicsVideoItem()
        videoItem.setSize(QSizeF(640, 480))
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.addItem(videoItem)
        graphicsView = QGraphicsView(scene)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(graphicsView)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoItem)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print('state: ' + str(self.mediaPlayer.state()))
        print('mediaStatus: ' + str(self.mediaPlayer.mediaStatus()))
        print('error: ' + str(self.mediaPlayer.error()))
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_L:
            print('loading')
            self.load()
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_P:
            print('playing')
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def load(self):
        local = QUrl.fromLocalFile('C:\\Users\\tank.sui\\Videos\\Wildlife.wmv')
        media = QMediaContent(local)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(media)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After Review your code， just list the root cause below.`QUrl.fromLocalFile`

```
local = QUrl.fromLocalFile('C:\\Users\\tank.sui\\Videos\\Wildlife.wmv')
```

---

Update@2017/3/15

To support several audio/video format, you need install corresponding decoder.

`LAVFilters`, I recommend it, you can download and install it from [RELEASE](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases).